# Can I keep the code of two template classes with circular dependencies in seperate header files?

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, circular-dependency

While thinking about my current programming project, I bumped into the following problem:
I have 2 template classes, where each one should be able to invoke a call on the other one, like outlined by the code below.

**Question:** Is there a way to keep this code in seperate header files (one for A and one for B)?

```
template <typename T>
class B;


template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    void foo() {
        m_b->bar();
    }

    void bar() {
        // ...
    }
private:
    B<T> *m_b;
};


template <typename T>
class B {
public:
    void foo() {
        m_a->bar();
    }

    void bar() {
        // ...
    }
private:
    A<T> *m_a;
};
```

EDIT: I just noticed, that the **real question** is:
If I have the files A.h and B.h, is there a way to call A::foo() from another file that just includes A.h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. using forward declaration.
2. move the implementation of the functions outside of the declaration of the template class.
3. in the cpp file (the implementation), you still need to include both headers though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works using forward declaration in both files. I think, I forgot to clarify this: If I have A.h and B.h, is there a way to call A::foo() from another file that does not include B.h?

Comment: @MalteLangkabel I don't see how. It invokes member `B::bar()` which must be known in the translation unit. You *could* get a little more abstract and make one of them a template-template parameter to the other, but you still need *both* to be known by the translation unit to do what you're describing.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Seems like you are right. Otherwise I could indirectly call B::bar() without ever including B.h.